# Remove an ERC20 contract from blockchain so it won't be visible in etherscan

Tags: contract-development

I made my first ERC20 and done some mistakes, I wanna delete it and create a new one with the same name and the same symbol

I have found how to delete the tokens but not the Contract itself so basically, the contract will remain in the etherscan.io site under Tokens.

What can i do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you had implemented the selfdestruct function, it would have been possible.

But if you have not, then there is nothing to do.

Pro tip => Use testnet(s)!

Comment: Ropsten, rinkeby, a private network if you want, somewhere that does not cost real monney